# How to get rid of similar argument in all functions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, refactoring

This is the active record class that handles the money transfers.

```
class Wallet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :deposits, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :deposit_requests, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :withdrawals, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :withdrawal_requests, dependent: :destroy

  def deposit_with_tax_deduction! amount
    deposit! amount
    deduct_tax(amount)
  end

  def deposit! amount
    deposits.create! amount: amount - tax_for(amount)
  end

  def withdraw! amount
    if can_spend? amount
      withdrawals.create! amount: amount 
    else
      raise "Недостаточно средств"
    end
  end

  def total
    deposits.sum(:amount) - withdrawals.sum(:amount) + deposit_requests.success.sum(:amount) - withdrawal_requests.success.sum(:amount)
  end

  def can_spend? amount
    total - amount > 0
  end

  def tax_for(amount)
    amount.to_f * Option.current.tax / 100
  end

  private
  def deduct_tax(amount)
    AdminWallet.deposit! amount
  end
end
```

I have same argument (`amount`) in practically every method in class. Is it a code smell, which can lead to bad consequences after years? What pattern should I follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fine.

Instance variables are generally considered as the state of an object. In your case, "amount" variable would be a needless mutation of the state, as it has no importance apart from the current execution.

However, it is important for me to mention that there are not strict rules here. It depends a lot on the nature of your class. Usually we differentiate between a *data object* and a *behavior object*. The former is generally more persistent while the latter is more configurable in its usage. Hence the "state" word has a diverse connotation in each.

Currently, as the "Wallet" class name suggests, you have a data object. Later on, you might refactor your code and create a "Transaction" class. In this kind of class, setting amount as an instance variable makes more sense. You could even easily use the Command pattern with it to undo your operations.

By the way, passing an exaggerated amount of parameters is a code smell which implies that you should consider splitting your code into more classes. And remember: do not try to solve problems you might have in couple of years. Focus on problems you have now.

Answer (score 0):

you can define amount as an `instance variable`, given that your methods are also `instance methods`

so

```
class Wallet < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  attr_accessor :amount

  def tax_for
  end
  ...
end
```

and you can use it by (ex)

```
wallet = Wallet.new
wallet.amount = 100
wallet.tax_for
```